# how to run parallel setup commands on circleci?

Tags: circleci

I want to be able to do something like the following pseudo code:

```
commands:
  - setup:
     parallel: true
     steps:
        - run ...
        - run ...
        - run ...
```

Everything I find on google and circle's docs is about parallel tests, but nothing about parallel tasks.

Note: I don't think running multiple parallel jobs and persisting/attaching to workspace will help, because the setup steps are not about our app's code, rather about the environment itself, so it would be very tricky to know what to persist/attach and where.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want to use `background-commands`

https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/configuration-reference/#background-commands

Although it only works for `run` steps and there is no built-in wait to wait a multiple background steps to finish before running another. Although you try work-around this limitation by writing a file to the disk after each background step and checking it somehow on the following step